# Is it possible to convert a solid 7z file to a non-solid 7z file?

Tags: 7zip

As per link: [Converting Zip to 7z](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/ceb99697/)

7-zip can't convert from one type to another.

But this discussion is almost 6 yrs old.

What I want to know is does the latest version support the conversion of solid archive into non-solid archive?If yes, how it can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to unzip the file and rezip it with 7z with non-solid option on.  There's no real option to just "convert" it without redoing the entire archive.